# Generate random samples at a certain point in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, scatter-plot

I have the following two data set:

```
  A=  (1,1)       1.9643
 (2,1)       2.2753
 (3,1)       2.9781
 (4,1)       2.9320
 (5,1)       3.5772
 (6,1)       4.0150
 (7,1)       3.3814
 (8,1)       3.9113
 (9,1)       2.7822
(10,1)       2.5518
(11,1)       3.3698
(12,1)       3.1048
(13,1)       1.9182
(14,1)       2.2638
(15,1)       2.6555
(16,1)       3.1855
(17,1)       3.6579
(18,1)       3.9113
(19,1)       3.6002
(20,1)       3.0357
(21,1)       1.5841
(22,1)       2.0103
(23,1)       1.9527
(24,1)       2.2753
(25,1)       2.3099
(26,1)       2.8283
(27,1)       3.0473
(28,1)       2.4827
(29,1)       2.5057
(30,1)       1.8721
(31,1)       2.0103
(32,1)       1.2269
(33,1)       1.8951
(34,1)       1.5610
(35,1)       1.5495
(36,1)       1.6878
(37,1)       1.4919
(38,1)       0.9620
(39,1)       1.1693
(40,1)       0.8122
(41,1)       0.9735
(42,1)       1.2500
(43,1)       1.3191
(44,1)       2.2292
(45,1)       2.4482
(46,1)       2.7938
(47,1)       2.0910
(48,1)       2.5403
(49,1)       0.9044
(50,1)       0.7662
 (1,2)       4.5957
 (2,2)       3.8589
 (3,2)       4.5651
 (4,2)       3.5519
 (5,2)       2.8560
 (6,2)       3.1937
 (7,2)       3.4291
 (8,2)       4.1761
 (9,2)       4.0431
(10,2)       4.6162
(11,2)       3.9101
(12,2)       3.0709
(13,2)       4.0534
(14,2)       4.3706
(15,2)       3.5008
(16,2)       4.2888
(17,2)       3.8692
(18,2)       3.4291
(19,2)       3.1221
(20,2)       3.3165
(21,2)       3.3575
(22,2)       3.2039
(23,2)       2.7843
   (24,2)       2.7127
(25,2)       2.9584
(26,2)       2.6309
 (27,2)       2.2931
  (28,2)       2.0373
   (29,2)       2.3853
   (30,2)       2.0577
   (31,2)       2.3546
    (32,2)       2.3239
    (33,2)       2.9174
     (34,2)       3.0709
    (35,2)       2.6923
     (36,2)       2.4057
     (37,2)       2.0271
      (38,2)       2.6820
   (39,2)       2.9276
    (40,2)       2.9992
   (41,2)       3.3881
   (42,2)       3.1937
   (43,2)       3.5109
   (44,2)       2.2010
  (45,2)       2.6411
  (46,2)       1.9656
   (47,2)       1.6177
  (48,2)       2.8867
 (49,2)       3.0198
 (50,2)       2.5899
```

Here, A is two dimensional sparse matrix where (i,i).

And B is (50,1) matrix, where the first 20 values are +1 and last 30 values are -1.

So the data point is look like this:

[image]

Now, I want to choose the (40,50) position of A and then want to generate 1000 random points within +/- 2 regions of the points.

So, the graph should be something like this:

[image]

Please let me know, how can I do it in matlab.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried anything? You should show that you have put some effort into the problem if you wish to get help on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mention a programming language, here is the general solution:

Assuming you want the data to be centered around (x,y), spread s, and label l.

Then you would for each object generatw two random Gaussians, scale them by the desired spread s, add the center vector (x,y), and append this vector to your data with the desired label.

Here, your center would be something like (45,45) and spread maybe 5 or just 1.

Comment: I'm so sorry. It should be in Matlab. I edited the question.. Thanks. Please let me know how can I do it.

Comment: I don't use Matlab. But above description should be straightforward to implement in Matlab, too.

Answer (score 0):

This generates and plots 1000 uniformly distributed random points within a +/- 2 region of position (40,50):

```
plot (40+4*rand(1000,1)-2, 50+4*rand(1000,1)-2,'o')
```

I know I ignored the "choosing a position from sparse matrix A"-part of your question. I hope that part is not crucial, and this will help you along anyway.

When you want other random distributions, check out `randn` (for gaussian) or other `rand*` functions.